# How can I find if a URLSessionDownloadTask is suspended (in discretionary mode)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using background downloads provided by iOS to download large files in the background. In the sessionConfig I'm setting the options for allowsCellularAccess and isDiscretionary. This 'suspends' the downloads when not enough power is available or on a cellular connection.

```
import Alamofire

class BackgroundDownload {
    var name: String
    var progress: Double
    var urlString: String
    var request: DownloadRequest?

    init(_ sessionName: String, urlString: String) {
        name = sessionName
        self.urlString = urlString
        progress = 0.0
    }

    private lazy var backgroundManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let bundleIdentifier = "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background"
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier + "." + name)
        sessionConfig.allowsCellularAccess = false
        sessionConfig.isDiscretionary = true
        return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: sessionConfig)
    }()

    func activate() -> Alamofire.SessionManager {
        return backgroundManager
    }

    var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
        get {
            return backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
        }
        set {
            backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

When a download is started, it is correctly suspended in cases where it makes sense. However I would like to detect these cases and give the user some feedback that the downloads are suspended because of one of these cases. Is there a way to find out if a download was suspended and why?

Comment: I wonder if [`urlSession(_:taskIsWaitingForConnectivity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/2908819-urlsession) and [`urlSession(_:task:willBeginDelayedRequest:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/2873415-urlsession) might at least tell you whether it is suspended, if not telling you why.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see Alamofire handling (much less providing closures to identify these cases). You might want to test in `URLSession` and if those provide what you need, and if so, request Alamofire authors (or do your own pull request) to provide exposure to these events.

Comment: The other possibility would be do incorporate [reachability](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#network-reachability) in your app, so you can at least identify cellular-only connections.